# display header in centre or page and logo to left of header with menu to right

Tags: html, css

i am using this css:

```
body,html {
    font-family:Arial;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#0C3;
}

.header {
    min-height:80px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.container {
    width:960px;

}


.logo {
    float:left;
    display:inline;
}
.menu {
    width:300px;
    float:right;
    display:inline;
}
```

to display a header the width ofmy container div (960px) with a logo to the left of the header and menu to the right

here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YxeTf/

but the header div is not displaying centre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `margin:auto;` to `.container` to center a `block` element within its parent `<div>`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DXmGB/)

```
.container {
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your header specific width - less than 960px

[DEMO jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxeTf/1/)

try this code for header ---

```
  .header {
      min-height:80px;
      width:700px;
      margin:0px auto;
      border:1px solid black;
    }
```